# $http:badreq - GET json Object

Tags: angularjs, json, http

I want to make an `$http` request **making use of the configuration object instead of the quick method**. The request is of 'GET' method and the url targets a local `json` file.

The code looks more or less like:

```
$http.get({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'data.json'
  }).then(function(res) {
    $scope.data = res;
  }, function(res) {
    console.log(res);
  })
```

The error I get is :

> Error: [$http:badreq]

Here's a 'working' [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/pbzT3iNGoSjhEnEEI0a7?p=preview) demonstrating the problem.

**The fact is that if I use the quick method `$http.get('clients.json')` it works.**

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**update your app.js file**

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $http({
    url: 'data.json',
    type: 'GET'
  }).then(function(res) {
    $scope.data = JSON.stringify(res.data);
  }, function(res) {
    console.log(res);
  })
});
```

[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/lpYJQVDYrvxpi3x0UgjA?p=preview)

Comment: I've mentioned twice that **I do not want to use the shortcut method**. But the configuration object.

Comment: i think you used get type twice.change get from $http.get({  to $http({

Comment: Oh, someone is blind. Thanks a lot !

Comment: glad to help you

Answer (score 0):

try this it works for me :  [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/XzSSQ5FezK3XZYnfi9eg)

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $http({method: 'GET',url : './data.json'}).then(function(res) {
    $scope.data = res;
  }, function(res) {
    console.log(res);
  })
});
```

Comment: I've mentioned twice that **I do not want to use the shortcut method**. But the configuration object.

Answer (score 0):

First on your `index.html`, you had `{data}}` instead of :

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    {{data}}
</body>
```

On your controller you have to invoke the `$http` as following (not using `$http.get`but just `$http`) :

```
$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'data.json'
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
  $scope.data = response.data;
}, function errorCallback(response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

See working update here https://plnkr.co/edit/OCPkPYsbcHv2snef5Bj3?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Seems your code is wrong, you already use $http.get, but still add {method: 'GET'}.

I guess you want to use $http request directly.

`$http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'data.json'
      }).then(function(res) {
        $scope.data = res;
      }, function(res) {
        console.log(res);
      })`